# Is Java's final keyword really needed in most cases?

Tags: java, jvm

I find that some Java IDEs have this rule about making things final without even asking the user.  For example, simply opening up a file lacking any 'final' keywords, the IDE would insert a bunch of them all over the place, most specifically on variables.

My argument has always been: "If the IDE can do it algorithmically, so can the JVM"

Does this argument hold water?  When should Java developers be using the 'final' keyword?  Should every variable that could be final be declared that way?

Thanks!

Comment: A variable should be final if you want to tell other developers: "Hey, you shouldn't change this!"

Comment: I highly recommend you [this](http://renaud.waldura.com/doc/java/final-keyword.shtml) article. In some cases `final` can improve the performance of your program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My argument has always been: "If the IDE can do it algorithmically, so can the JVM"
>
> Does this argument hold water?

Nope. Because when the IDE does it (and I haven't seen any do it *by default* without asking, even though you can explicitly configure it to do it that way) the developer can check that it's really the decision they wanted. This *prevents* other code from doing things against the developer's wishes.

If it were *only* done at execution time, that would defeat the whole purpose. If I make a field `final` to prevent other code from modifying it, I want a compile-time error if other code tries to modify it. If it's just left up to the JVM, I can't rely on code *not* modifying it.

> When should Java developers be using the 'final' keyword?

For fields, when the field is meant to be initialized in the constructor and not changed thereafter.

For classes, when you haven't designed for your class to be subclasses (IMO).

For methods, when you haven't designed your code for subclasses to override the method.

For local variables, where you want to access the variable in an anonymous inner class. (You can also use them for other local variables of course - I don't tend to, but I know some folks who do. That difference isn't visible to code outside the method of course.)

Comment: ...and for local variables, when these are used in anonymous classes?

Comment: @Axel: Yup, true. Will add.

Comment: Thanks for the response... It seems to me that you're saying that 'final' should be used to express intent about how a variable/method/class is used/modified.  Therefore wouldn't a blanket rule to automatically add final keywords in defeat the purpose?

For example, the IDE might decide that since you don't actually modify x that x should be declared final, but maybe that's not necessarily your intent about how x ought to be used?

Comment: @ScottFrazer: The blanket rule is there to encourage lazy programmers to prefer final fields (or whatever) over non-final ones. Bear in mind that it's easier to *remove* finality later than to add it. But as I say, I haven't seen any IDEs which do this *by default* anyway.

Comment: It is only easy to remove finality later if you are the author of the source code.  If you are using a library, this can be a real pain to work around.

Comment: @TomCarchrae: Yes, but that's usually a sign that you *shouldn't* be trying to remove it, IME. This goes alongside "design for inheritance or prohibit it".

Comment: Yeah I don't use IDEs but I think a lot of people just configure their IDE to do this automatically because I see diffs where it's added across a bunch of files in a way that's pretty obvious that the developer didn't do it by hand.

Comment: In a well designed library, for sure, final means don't touch this.    In other libraries, such as ones made by lazy programmers, I've had to copy out entire classes which made just me sad.  So, the blanket rule might make better code in your project, but makes for worse libraries.

Comment: @TomCarchrae: Are you talking about fields, classes or methods? In almost all cases I'd generally rather that they were prematurely final than prematurely non-final...

Comment: eg, overriding/fixing parser behaviour (a 3 line method was made final) so had to copy entire parser class.

Comment: @TomCarchrae: Right, that's the sort of thing where I *prefer* final - because if a method hasn't been designed for inheritance, it can seriously screw things up if you override it. I would try to apply composition wherever possible for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You're being too vague, final means many things:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)

Also, see this related discussion: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/why-declare-final-variables-inside-methods which links to the following artcle:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=23

> Use the final keyword liberally to communicate your intent. The final keyword has more than one meaning :
>
> - a final class cannot be extended
> - a final method cannot be overridden
> - final fields, parameters, and local variables cannot change their
>     value once set
>
> In the last case, "value" for primitives is understood
>   in the usual sense, while "value" for objects means the object's
>   identity, not its state. Once the identity of a final object reference
>   is set, it can still change its state, but not its identity. Declaring
>   primitive fields as final automatically ensures thread-safety for that
>   field.
>
> Some habitually declare parameters as final, since this almost always
>   the desired behaviour. Others find this verbose, and of little real
>   benefit.
>
> Consistently using final with local variables (when appropriate) can
>   be useful as well. It brings attention to the non-final local
>   variables, which usually have more logic associated with them (for
>   example, result variables, accumulators, loop variables). Many find
>   this verbose. A reasonable approach is to use final for local
>   variables only if there is at least one non-final local variable in
>   the method ; this serves to quickly distinguish the non-final local
>   variables from the others.
>
> Using final :
>
> - clearly communicates your intent
> - allows the compiler and virtual
>     machine to perform minor optimizations
> - clearly flags items which are
>     simpler in behaviour - final says,  "If you are looking for
>     complexity, you won't find it here."

Comment: Actually I'd say the two main contexts are *classes* and fields. But the other two are valid too, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet - yeah, lovely overloaded keywords!  it is an easy language because it has only 50 key words.  but many of them have a few meanings.  i'm looking at you too static.

Answer (score 0):

A local variable can be used in an inner class only if it is `final`.

The `final` modifier can be used to protect yourself against slips in setter methods.

```
public void setLimit(int limit) {
    /*this.*/limit = limit;
}
```

is obviously wrong; putting in the `this.` was needed.  Using `final` as in

```
public void setLimit(final int limit) {
    limit = limit;
}
```

turns that into a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

> Should every variable that could be final be declared that way?

Yes.

A lot of people don't realize how much the compiler can do to help you avoid common problems:

```
// Final parameters cannot be reassigned.  This sometimes happens accidentally
// and sometimes because people see them as convenient local variables.
publc void myFunction(final int myIntParam) {

    // Let's declare a local variable
    final String myLocalString;

    // ... there's some code here ...

    // Here, the compiler knows whether this variable has been assigned
    // The programmer knows that it has been assigned only once
    return myLocalString.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
}
```

Comment: While I completely agree for *instance* variables, I can't remember the last time I came across a problem where I'd accidentally reassigned a local variable. It's easier to see all assignments to a local variable because the code for a method is generally much smaller than the code for an entire class. (And if it's not, that suggests you should refactor the method.) I find that the `final` modifier adds too much clutter to be worthwhile here. I'd be happy enough if local variables and parameters were final by *default* though.

Comment: I can't really argue.  I've been forced to code more defensively in certain projects due to some really bad maintainers.  I guess it depends on how much you trust the next person who is going to work on the code.  Also, with aggressive refactoring, one tends to use considerably fewer local variables in the first place, so that's another way that refactoring diminishes the need for this.